# How to make the LayerSwitch showing its div as default in OpenLayer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, openlayers

I have searched on google on how too make this, but I can find any sample code to make this done. I want to make the div of google option to be showing. Because it is toggled hide on its default settings.

Instead of this when site is loaded:

[image]

I want to be like this when site is loaded:

[image]

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I have tried to make this but still no luck

```
var ovControl = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher();

ovControl.showControls = function(){
    return true;
};

map.addControl( ovControl );
```

[This](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/LayerSwitcher-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher.maximizeDiv) documentation shows the option to add when initializing the object. But I can't figure out how to use it. 'maximizeDiv' is I think the option to be used.

Comment: I have already got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution.

```
map.addControl( ovControl);
ovControl.maximizeControl();
```